# Knockout popover template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, popover

How can I get the user name inside my popover template?

```
<script type="html/text" id="editTemplate">
```

user:

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/gm79cr22/64/

Thanks

Comment: I think you should be using a [component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html)

Comment: [Knockstrap](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/#modal) could be another option

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to solve this, is to use jQuery to create and get the popover dom node directly, so you can use it to apply the binding to it.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  self = this;
  self.exampleText = ko.observable("Click me!");

  var data = [{
      name: "User1",
      date: "01/01/2017"
    },
    {
      name: "User2",
      date: "01/01/2017"
    },
    {
      name: "User3",
      date: "01/01/2017"
    },
    {
      name: "User4",
      date: "01/01/2017"
    }
  ];

  self.users = ko.observableArray(data);

};

ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var cssSelectorForPopoverTemplate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var popOverTemplate = $("<div class='my-knockout-popver'>" + $(cssSelectorForPopoverTemplate).html() + "</div>");

    $(element).popover({
      content: popOverTemplate,
      html: true,
      trigger: 'hover'
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, popOverTemplate[0]);
  },
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css');
/*.example-container{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
    font-size:24px;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: users ">
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td>
      <div data-placement="top" data-title="Info" data-bind="popover: '#editTemplate'">
        <i class="fa fa-adjust" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <!-- This is the popover template  -->
        <script type="text/html" id="editTemplate">
          User: <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </script>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```